# iPhone to Mac Development

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos

I am an iPhone developer and know that framework well. With the Mac App store on the verge, I'l like to learn more about Mac development. Are there any good guides/tutorial/etc. to help with the transition? I have looked around and not found much. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I asked a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984159/tips-for-an-ios-developer-to-learn-mac-programming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically need to learn the difference between `UIKit` and `AppKit`. (`Foundation` and `Core Foundation` are the same on both platforms.) They are subtly different; there are more frameworks which comes with the OS X than with the iOS; a framework with the same name might have more functionality on OS X, etc.

But that's basically it,  if you distribute the app through the Mac App Store, because you don't have to learn how to package things by yourself.

The best book on Cocoa programming for Mac is [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321503619), but it might be too elementary for an experienced iOS programmer. But it's still a good book.

I guess we'll see a flood of books for people like you, showing the way of Mac development to competent iPhone programmers; but it hasn't happened yet. Maybe you might write one, from your own experience :)

Answer (score 0):

Going the other way, I found that the skills that transfer are really just the low level stuff like Objective-C, Foundation and Core Foundation and the tools are the same.

Also a lot of the low level concepts are the same.  There are still targets and action, IBOutlets and IBActions.  However on a higher level things are very different.  There is, for instance, a table view but you tend to use it in a different way and only when an actual table is required rather than as a framework for a whole GUI idiom.  Also, table views have more than one column.

There are many advantages, for example you have much more freedom in how your UI will look.  And you use garbage collection.  With GC everything you've learned about Cocoa memory management becomes instantly redundant.  It's very liberating.