# Ressources for OSX-from-IOS-developers

Tags: ios, macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tips for an iOS developer to learn Mac programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984159/tips-for-an-ios-developer-to-learn-mac-programming)

After having spent a year in IOS-development, I'd like to broaden my horizon and jump into OSX-development. Does anyone have a good ressource, book, online or otherwise? I'm looking for: 'the differneces in short and fast are', instead of 'first, download xcode'. Any tipps appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the standard for learning Cocoa on Mac OSX.  I went through it and found it to be very good:

http://www.bignerdranch.com/book/cocoa_programming_for_mac_os_x_rd_edition_

Also, this book was good but felt more like a reference and less like a tutorial which the previous book was:

[http://www.amazon.com/Cocoa-Programming-Developers-Handbook-Chisnall/dp/0321639634/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1316367686&sr=8-3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321639634)

After those, this advanced book is good:

http://www.bignerdranch.com/book/advanced_mac_os_x_programming_rd_edition_

I also recommend the WWDC videos if you pay for the dev program.  Good hands on practical advice and walk throughs on good topics.

Answer (score 2):

I advice to use learning resources from http://developer.apple.com

Comment: Always great - especially the guides on each topic (for example "Introduction to View Programming Guide for Cocoa").  After the guides, great class references.